# Database or XML performs well in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my app i have to store some data. I'm thinking of XML instead of database. But little confused that which is faster.The data contains some URLs and some strings.
Please let me know xml or database is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what kind of app you are trying to develop.

Like a weather forecast app , you just need to save several provinces/cities info .
I think xml is better . Because it is more easy to implement and maintain.

And Like a diary app ,　the data increase very fast. So DB is more better , because the large  xml file would affect the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks these kinds of questions are more discussive and most likely to be voted for closing.

Nevertheless, the performance depends on the size of the stored data.

While an XML file is small, it will generally perform better then the DB (considering an overhead you will need to go through while deploying it, etc.)

But when you need to store a lot of structured data - DB will after all will the race.

And since I think that the phone is not a place for an RDBMS engine, I go with XML storage on WP7 for now.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I've experience with WP7 and the built in database is that there's a bit more upfront performance cost to using the database engine than there is with straight Isolated Storage and XML.  It was enough of a performance hit during application startup that it was apparent to the user that there was a delay in populating their data.

I would say that for small amounts of data where you just need to read and display, XML is probably your best bet, but for data where you might have to do a lot of aggregating and grouping, it will probably wind up being easier to do with SQL, so you'll need to measure the trade-offs between performance and ease-of-coding/maintenance before you make your decision.